# NSCoding with a singleton subclass

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

I have a number of derived classes whose common base-class conforms to `NSCoding`. I want to be able to easily encode an `NSArray` holding instances of the various deriving classes.

```
@interface Base : NSObject <NSCoding>
@end

@interface DerivedSingleton : Base
+(instancetype) sharedInstance;
@end

@interface DerivedNonSingleton : Base
@end
```

The deriving singleton should have only one instance in the running system. It doesn't actually have any state to encode in the coder. It's instance is created with the `+(void) initialize` class method.

```
DerivedSingleton *sharedInstance;

@implementation DerivedSingleton
+(void) initialize
{
  sharedInstance = [DerivedSingleton new];
}

+(instancetype) sharedInstance
{
  return sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

So, if I now make an array holding instances of the classes, and encode it:

```
NSArray *const array = @[
  [DerivedSingleton sharedInstance], 
  [DerivedNonSingleton new], 
  [DerivedNonSingleton new]];

NSData *const arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: array];
```

When I later decode it, I require references to the shared singleton to decode as references to the shared singleton…

```
NSArray *const decodedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: arrayData];
[decodedArray objectAtIndex: 0] == [DerivedSingleton sharedInstance];
```

---

I note that the `NSCoding` protocol wants me to implement `initWithCoder:` for the singleton, but during decode, I want this class to provide the shared instance, not a newly `alloc`ed object.

Comment: Totally unsure why there are votes to close this question? Could you please provide a comment if you're asking for that. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];

    return [self.class shared];
}
```

Comment: :-) I'd just found `replacementObjectForCoder:` and `awakeAfterUsingCoder:`, and had implemented a Placeholder object … your solution seems simpler :-)

Comment: Is it worth throwing in a `self = [super init];` prior to the return, there, or is self.class already set up?

Comment: @Benjohn I'd say add the `self = [super init]`, but I'd bet `self.class` is already set up anyway.

Comment: Thanks Tom – I'll be able to let you know if it works in a little while :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something similar with the singleton:

## .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#pragma mark - Interface

@interface SerializableSingleton : NSObject <NSCoding>

#pragma mark - Class methods

#pragma mark - Shared instance

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "SerializableSingleton.h"

#pragma mark - Reference

static id _serializableSingletonSharedInstance = nil;

#pragma mark - Implementation

@implementation SerializableSingleton

#pragma mark - Class methods

#pragma mark - Shared instance

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {

    @synchronized([self class]) {
        if (_serializableSingletonSharedInstance == nil) {
            _serializableSingletonSharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return _serializableSingletonSharedInstance;
}

#pragma mark - Instance methods

#pragma mark - <NSCoding>

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    @synchronized([self class]) {
        if (_serializableSingletonSharedInstance == nil) {
            if (self = [super init]) {
                // decode the desired data...
            }
            _serializableSingletonSharedInstance = self;
        }
    }
    return _serializableSingletonSharedInstance;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    // encode the desired data
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi @holex, thanks, but I don't think that answers the question? The issue is that the shared instance will be in an array with other objects that are not singletons, but derive from the same base class. The whole array needs to support `NSCoding`. It's not the shared instance that I specifically want to store. When I decode an array store like this, any shared singleton references must decode as references to the shared singleton instance.

Comment: I've added rather a lot to the questions – sorry if it was not clear before.

Comment: @Benjohn, oh I see. that is true, you need to update the singleton references after unarchiving the items of array in that situation, but you can put such a code into the `-initWithCoder:` method before your return the `self`.

Comment: @Benjohn, no problems, I've updated my answer slightly.